# Creating a List of Range

Tags: scala

I'm trying to get `List(0,1,2,...n)`

Is there a cleaner/better way than:

```
scala> List(0 to 9)
res0: List[scala.collection.immutable.Range.Inclusive] = List(Range(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 
                                                                   5, 6, 7, 8, 9))

scala> List(0 to 9).flatten
res1: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The best way might be:

```
(0 to 9).toList
```

Answer (score 6):

```
scala> List.range(0, 10)
res0: List[Int] = List(0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9)
```

Answer (score 1):

Also

```
List(0 to 9: _*)
```

I suspect though that `List.range` is the most efficient one.

Comment: Because it does not need to create an intermediate collection. It's just my guess, you would need to run a proper benchmark to see if the difference is noticeable.

Comment: `Range` is almost free, consisting of just 3 numbers, so I doubt there'd be any difference. I'd go with the most readable.

Comment: @LuigiPlinge that's true, but that object is allocated nevertheless